# How to navigate to activity on click of notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have one activity lets say `SplashActivity`. I have declared this activity in manifest as below

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />          
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**This works fine with following condition** 
   App in background and notification comes with no **click_action** in payload and user clicks on notification, the user navigates to `SplashActivity`.

**This not works fine with the following conditions**
 App in background and notification comes with some **click_action** in payload and user clicks on notification, the user remains on the same screen and notification disappear.

How to open `SplashActivity` in these both cases ?

 Please help, 
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you must specify a content intent defined with a PendingIntent object and pass it to setContentIntent().

The following snippet shows how to create a basic intent to open an activity when the user taps the notification:

```
// Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app


 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);


NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true);
```

For more info, Refer this official doc
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#java

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Swati , but i already tried it and it did not help.